# What does this bracket notation mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am currently taking MIT6.006 and I came across this problem on the problem set. Despite the fact I have learned Discrete Mathematics before, I have never seen such notation before, and I would like to know what it means and how it works, Thank you:
$$ f_3(n) = \binom n2$$
[(Transcribed from screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blEjd.png)

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{n}{k}$ usually denotes the [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) which is explicitly given as $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
for non-negative integers $k \le n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the binomial coefficient:
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!)}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's the binomial coefficient, which counts the number of 2-subsets of an $n$-element set.

It's computed as $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

It generalises to $n\choose k$.